# Does this species appear in the film version of a Wrinkle in Time?

Tags: a-wrinkle-in-time

The collection *Barlowe's Guide to Extraterrestrials* features drawings of Wayne Barlowe's visual interpretations of alien creatures from a variety of different authors including *A Wrinkle in Time's* Ixchel- a species of four-armed beings with tentacles for fingers and bodies covered with grey fur.

I first started to watch the 2018 movie based on this book hoping to see these aliens- unfortunately I never made it all the way through the film and what I did see gave me the impression I wouldn't see them even if I had- do these aliens appear in the film at all?

Comment: The... um... Ixchelian? Ixchelite? Furry-tentacled-aliens were SUPPOSED to appear in the 2018 film but apparently their scene was cut because the director decided the movie flowed better without it. I don't have a citation for this; it's on the Wrinkle in Time wiki. The scene may be available on youtube. For what it's worth, the aliens DID appear in the 2003 movie adaptation.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701- maybe you should put this as an answer, from the look of things it's probably the best I'm going to get.